# How to get distinct row in entityframework?

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5

How I can get to distinct row from a table using entity-framework.

Like i want to get, 2 distinct row where name is unique:

```
1| 04-DEC-15|   01-JAN-01   |4  |1  |10000.0    |0.0    |ship   |None   |LP_Joc1_B1 |01-JAN-01| 0

6| 28-DEC-15 |  01-JAN-01   |4  |1  |30000.0    |0.0    |ship   |None   |LP_Joc1_B2 |01-JAN-01| 0
```

[image]

Comment: but you do not have name column in your  table.

Answer (score 1):

```
//distinct based on a specific property (in this case Name)
List<Objects> listObjects = (from obj in db.Objects                             
                                select obj).GroupBy(n => new {n.Name})
                                           .Select(g => g.FirstOrDefault())
                                           .ToList();
```

Comment: Hi Pranav.  I am getting this error while retrieving the value from the database.     "List<LiftingProgram> Joclift = (from obj in context.LiftingPrograms select obj).GroupBy(n => new { n.Name }).Select(x => x.FirstOrDefault()).ToList();"                                                    Error: {"Oracle 11.2.0.2.0 does not support APPLY"}

Comment: Try `.Min` instead of `.FirstOrDefault`. Oracle 11.2 doesn't have apply which is used internally. It's supported in `Oracle Database 12c`.